# Regex pattern to match - Javascript

Tags: regex

I need a sample regular expression to test in Javascript  - input starts with one number between 1 to 16 and is followed by 1 letter between A to E only. eg 2B, 8D, 11E, 16A

I have this regex `^([1-9]|[0-1][0-6])[A-E]$` but unable to get appropriate result.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `^(?:[1-9]|1[0-6])[A-E]$`

Comment: Try: `(?:1[0-6]|[1-9])[A-E]` ... your current pattern is only slightly off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[0-1][0-6]` part matches numbers from `00` to `16`.

You want

```
^(?:[1-9]|1[0-6])[A-E]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m0nfap/1) and a [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-6%5D)%5BA-E%5D%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
  -`(?:[1-9]|1[0-6])` - a digit from `1` to `9` or `1` followed with a digit from `0` to `6`
- `[A-E]` - `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` or `E`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It worked - many thanks for your time, support and regex useful info.